# import .txt a sql server

Tags: sql-server

Buen día.
Requiero importar a una tabla, una gran cantidad de información en un archivo plano `.txt` y la información esta separada por `|`. Usando la sentencia `bulk..insert..with..etc`; no fue posible importar, porque la data sobrepasa el tamaño de filas:

> Cannot create a row of size 15817 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060. The statement has been terminated.).

es posible realizar un tipo de `select` al archivo plano, y lo resultante importarlo a la tabla que deseo, ya que en verdad no necesito todas las columnas que hay en el archivo.
Agradezco su ayuda, he buscado ya bastante y no he encontrado cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Pareciera que el `bulk insert` no está interpretando el salto de línea, entonces sigue considerando campos como parte de una única fila. ¿Sabe el o los caracteres de salto de línea del archivo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar abrir el archivo en excel, convertirlo en columnas separadas por caracteres (Datos->Texto en columnas->Delimitados ->Separadores).

Guardar el archivo como un nuevo CSV después de quitar las columnas que no necesites y luego usar la herramienta de [SQL Import and Export Wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) para importarlo.

Si el problema es el tamaño de una columna puedes intentar [esta respuesta aceptada en MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6008789e-d9c3-492a-8e52-371bfb542f01/how-to-increase-row-size-in-sql-2008?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: Gracias por responder...porbexcel se demora bastante tiempo en abrir y es un archivo que se va estar actualizando constantemente

Answer (score 0):

Por la herramienta de SQL Server, SQL Import & Export Wizard puedes hacerlo directamente sobre tu archivo TXT. Sobre la BD en la que quieres tener los datos, das clic derecho y buscas la opción "Import Data", cuando aparezca la ventana del asistente, y seleccionas, en la siguiente ventana, el proveedor "Flat File Source" como origen de datos y llenas los datos que te piden. Ten especial cuidado en definir bien las columnas requeridas mediante el delimitador de columna y también de seleccionar las columnas deseadas. Al dar siguiente, seleccionas el proveedor para el destino de datos y la información que se solicita. Al dar clic en la siguiente ventana, puedes editar ya por cada columna requerida, el tipo de datos y otra información que requieras. Al dar siguiente, la sugerencia es guardar el paquete SSIS para uso posterior de acuerdo con lo que indicas, bien sea en SQL Server o en el sistema de archivos.

Con lo anterior, tienes algo de control sobre el procedimiento e incluso, con el paquete guardado, puedes ejecutarlo manual o de manera programada mediante un JOB en SQL Server.